# How to implement pagination in a merged set of queries when implementing a logical OR

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In the [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#query_limitations) documentation, it states clearly the limitations of support for query filters with logical OR.

For example:

```
const userPostsQuery = query(postsRef, where("author", "==", uid);

const publicPostsQuery = query(postsRef, where("public", "==", true);
```

If as in the above example, we need to get a list of both, user posts and public posts all sorted together by date, ie: Both queries need to be OR-ed together, such a feature is not available in Firestore and we will have to run both queries separately, and then merge and sort the results on the client-side.

I'm fine with such a sad workaround. but what if the total number of posts can be huge? thus we need to implement a pagination system where each page shows 50 posts max. How can this be done with such a sad workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Firestore has very limited operators and aggregation options. However, it has limited OR support with an Array type.

A solution that could simplify your use case is to introduce a new field of type array in your post document. Let's say this field is named *a*. When you create your document, *a* is equal to `[authorId, 'public']` if the post is public, `[authorId]` otherwise.

Then, you can query your need using the `array-contains-any` operator:

```
const q = query(postRef, where('a', 'array-contains-any', [authorId, 'public']));
```

You can easily add pagination with `limit`, `orderBy`, `startAt`, and `startAfter` functions.

Comment: This approach is definitely valid and seems to be the best approach available, and I've thought of it. but unfortunately, the example I provided is just a simplified hypothetical example. I can't use this in the real use case that I have.